# Read single XML line with Java

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to read a single XML line that looks like this:

```
<position lat="59.3252414125" long="18.0750236375" accuracy="1000"></position>
```

The goal here is take the values of "lat", "long" and "accuracy" and put them in three Java variables.

EDIT: I guess I should've mentioned that the line is read from an XML, so it's not easily editable as it would appear.

Comment: what xml framework are you using?

Comment: so, what is the trouble?

Comment: you have essentially 2 choices with default jdk : sax/stax and dom

Comment: I smell homework or a take-home interview question.

Comment: I've tried working down a bigger scale SAX-parser that I've used for reading a highscore list, but I just get confused somewhere along the way. I've tried looking around for a simple way of reading, but most I find follow the multi-element structure. I guess I'm just not that good at XML-reading.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: you're right, I was rather thinking about parsing, but mapping could also be used to get the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
    String s = "<position lat=\"59.3252414125\" long=\"18.0750236375\" accuracy=\"1000\"></position>";
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(s));
    DOMParser dp = new DOMParser();
    dp.parse(is);
    Document doc = dp.getDocument();
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("position");
    Node n = nl.item(0);
    NamedNodeMap nnm = n.getAttributes();
    String lat = nnm.getNamedItem("lat").getFirstChild().getTextContent();
    String longg = nnm.getNamedItem("long").getFirstChild().getTextContent();
    String accuracy = nnm.getNamedItem("accuracy").getFirstChild().getTextContent();
```

Suggested Readings:

- http://www.cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch05.html
- http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html
- Look into [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/) it's too simple and good.

Comment: Is this dealt with in much difference if the XML-line in question is read from an XML-file? Cause I've isolated the last 3 lines to cause a NullPointerException.

Comment: @Zephyr if you're reading from file use: `dp.parse("complete\\file\\path\\fully\\escaped");`

Comment: It's working now! I exchanged .getFirstChild().getTextContent(); with getNodeValue());

Answer (score 1):

Using only the String.split() function:

```
package com.stackoverflow.q5231285;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xmlLine = "<position lat=\"59.3252414125\" long=\"18.0750236375\" accuracy=\"1000\"></position>";
        String splitResult[] = xmlLine.split("\"");

        Double latValue = Double.parseDouble(splitResult[1]);
        Double longValue = Double.parseDouble(splitResult[3]);
        int accuracy = Integer.parseInt(splitResult[5]);
        System.out.println(latValue + " " + longValue + " " + accuracy);
    }
}
```

Comment: not the right way to parse organized XML data. it's cruelty when data is so much clean. May solve the immediate problem, but bad practice. Not down-voting though.

Comment: Certainly not a good practice for parsing XML, but the problem asks for parsing a String with the given format. Of course if the attribute order changes my code won't work, but I don't see any problem loosing flexibility for simplicity when flexibility is not required. Sometimes we (the programmers) add non explicit requirements when there's no need no do it.

Answer (score 1):

If youre using SAX or StAX, you will probably end up with a [XMLEventReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html) or a [XMLStreamReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html). Both have methods to determine the type of XML `Element` or `Event` currently in processing, defined in the `XMLStreamConstants`. 
If you have the  `position` Element, just get the next Event with `nextEvent()` if you're using the EventReader, or get the attribute value with `getAttributeValue()`if you're using the StreamReader