# Converting simple XML line into a Map elegantly

Tags: java, xml

I'm doing some work with the stackoverflow data set in Java and have a string like this:

```
 <row Id="1" PostId="35314" Score="8" Text="not sure why this is getting
     downvoted -- it is correct! Double check it in your compiler if you
     don't believe him!" CreationDate="2008-09-06T08:07:10.730" UserId="1" />
```

(newlines added for readability)

Assuming the data above is in a String, what would be the most elegant way to convert it into a `Map<String, String>`, with the keys being the labels (`"Id"`, `"Score"`, ...) and the values being Strings containing the values (`"1"`, `"35314"`, ...)?  I want to do this elegantly, readably, and succinctly because is this code will be seen by a lot of people. I wrote something up that does all kinds of string manipulation and it's just ugly.

In the framework I am using, I have to process one row at a time, so I can't parse the entire XML structure (all the lines) at once. I have to do one line at a time.

Comment: Why not just parsing it as XML line by line? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231285/read-single-xml-line-with-java

Comment: Can you also explain how you ended up with a framework that handles an XML file line by line?

Comment: Using Hadoop with the LineRecordReader. It passes me data line by line and splits it across processes.

Comment: Related: http://xmlandhadoop.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static Map<String, String> transformXmlToMap(String xml) {
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
        DocumentBuilder bldr = factory
                .newDocumentBuilder();

        doc = bldr.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    NamedNodeMap attributeMap = doc.getDocumentElement().getAttributes();

    for (int i = 0; i < attributeMap.getLength(); ++i) {
        Attr n = (Attr) attributeMap.item(i);

        map.put(n.getName(), n.getValue());
    }

    return map;
}
```

This will use the org.w3c.* libraries for processing.  It isn't as lightweight as a straightforward String processing approach is, so hopefully someone can come up with something better.  Storing the DocumentBuilder as a static final variable would help speed up the processing, as you don't need to create one every time.

Answer (score 2):

See the [JAXB - HashMap](http://www.coderanch.com/t/534260/XML/JAXB-HashMap) thread for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SAX parser for this. It processes XML row by row as per your requirement.

Comment: I should be more clear-- i only have access to one row at a time. It's not that I don't want to process them line-by-line, I have to.

Comment: Still you can use SAX parser, you just have to call the parser for each row. I think this is possible but performance wise its not a good solution. In this scenario, manual parsing will perform better than SAX parser.

Comment: I think SAX parsing might perform reasonably so long as you take care to reuse the parser. But yes, there will still be a significant start-up overhead when parsing such a small document.

Answer (score 1):

If you chose SAX you should extend the [DefaultHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html) class, just like that example.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class RowDefaultHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (!"row".equals(qName)) {
            return;
        }

        Map<String, String> row = new HashMap<String, String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < attributes.getLength(); i++) {
            row.put(attributes.getQName(i), attributes.getValue(i));
        }

        System.out.println(row);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

public class RowDefaultHandlerUsage {

    public static void main(String...args) throws Exception {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

        CharSequence data = new StringBuilder()
            .append("<rows>")
                .append("<row Id=\"1\" PostId=\"35314\" Score=\"8\" />")
                .append("<row Id=\"2\" PostId=\"35315\" Score=\"3\" />")
            .append("<rows>");
        InputStream source = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.toString().getBytes());

        RowDefaultHandler rowHandler = new RowDefaultHandler();
        parser.parse(source, rowHandler);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
{Id=1, PostId=35314, Score=8}
{Id=2, PostId=35315, Score=3}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was found in mrdp.utils. Any one else have written this in core Java.

```
public class MRDPUtils {

    public static final String[] REDIS_INSTANCES = { "p0", "p1", "p2", "p3",
            "p4", "p6" };

    // This helper function parses the stackoverflow into a Map for us.
    public static Map<String, String> transformXmlToMap(String xml) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        try {
            String[] tokens = xml.trim().substring(5, xml.trim().length() - 3)
                    .split("\"");

            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length - 1; i += 2) {
                String key = tokens[i].trim();
                String val = tokens[i + 1];

                map.put(key.substring(0, key.length() - 1), val);
            }
        } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.err.println(xml);
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```