# Parsing XML in Java line by line

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'd like to parse an XML file in Java *line by line* because the framework of a file that I got is a bit different than usual. It is not nested; each tag is in its own line.

Part of XML file:

```
<sentence><flag>3</flag></sentence>
<word><text>Zdravo</text></word>
<phoneme><onephoneme>z</onephoneme></phoneme>
<phoneme><onephoneme>d</onephoneme></phoneme>
<phoneme><onephoneme>r</onephoneme></phoneme>
<phoneme><onephoneme>"a:</onephoneme></phoneme>
<phoneme><onephoneme>v</onephoneme></phoneme>
<phoneme><onephoneme>O</onephoneme></phoneme>
<sentence><flag>0</flag></sentence>
<word><text>moje</text></word>
...
```

I searched and found a lot of different ways to parse an XML file but all of them scan the whole file and I don't want that because my file is almost 100k lines and for now (and maybe even later) I only need first 800 lines so it would be much faster to just parse line by line. I don't know how many lines I really need in advance but I'd like to count how many times I reach tag  and stop at certain count (for now it's 17 - that's around line 800).

Tutorials that I found:

- nested XML: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/
- nested XML: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html
- single line XML with attributes: [Read single XML line with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231285/read-single-xml-line-with-java)

Each sentence is then separated into word and each word into phonemes, so in the end I'd have 3 ArrayLists: flags, words and phonemes.

I hope I gave you enough information.

Thank you.

Comment: I would strongly recommend a SAX parser, because it will keep you flexible, in case the line structure changes. You can e.g. break out of the SAX parsing by throwing a custom exception in the callback methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines are not really  relevant for XML, you can have all your XML worth of 100K lines in one single line. What you need to do is count by elements/nodes you parse. Use a SAX parser, it is event based, it will notify you when an element start and when it ends. Whenever you get an element you are interested in parsing increment the counter, this assumes you know the elements you are interested in,  from your example, those would be:

```
<sentence>
<word>
<phoneme>
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you! I did it with _SAXParser_. It is much easier then I thought from the beginning - I didn't know what `start` and `length` are representing.
Still don't know how to finish when I reach the 18th sentence but I read that it's easier to just let the parser parse the whole XML because it's faster than doing an exception.

Comment: @bajagaraja cool, you're welcome. Unfortunately there is no other way than throwing an exception to cancel the parser after a certain number of elements. I would recommend though to use a custom Exception for example `ParseLimitReachedException` to stop parsing, then your document might grow to a point where you can't afford to let it run till the end. Using a custom Exception will allow you to differentiate it from other Exceptions related to XML parsing itself.

Comment: I read that if the file is not that big that the "cost" of an exception can be more than just parsing the whole XML file so for now I'll just leave it here because it takes a few seconds to finish. But I saw some examples with custom Exceptions and will keep that in mind if necessary. Thanks again.

Comment: @bajagaraja cool, if you could solve your problem then you might want to accept any of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Stubbs suggested SAX and StAX but if your file will be really big I would use [VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/) it is at least 3 times faster then SAX and much more flexible. Processing 2GB XMLs is not a problem at all

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a file line by line, is has nothing to do with XML. Simply use an [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) as it provides an readLine method.
With a simple counter you can check, how many lines you have already read and quit the loop after you hit the 800 mark.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't know in advance that I need 800 lines. My limiter is the number of <sentence> tags. So I'd like to quit the loop when I hit let's say 17 sentences. Can I still do it like you suggested?

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Korashen, if you can guarantee that the files you will be dealing with are going to follow a flat, line by line structure then you are probably best off pretending that the files are not XML at all, and using a normal `BufferedReader`.

However, if you need to parse it as XML, then a *streaming* XML reader should be able to do what you want. According to [Java XML Parser for huge files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969713/java-xml-parser-for-huge-files), **SAX** or **StAX** are the standard choices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sax parser. In the xml is traversed line by line and appropriate events are triggered. In addition you could use [org.xml.sax.Locator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Locator.html) to identify the line number and throw an exception when you encounter line 800 to stop parsing.